# Website with WooCommerce and Membership based products showing "No results found" after login page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, divi, woocommerce-memberships

I am having issue for a week or more with my website that used to function pretty well before.
The website is jaka.mk and it sells pilates/exercising programs as membership plans.

The issue is that, after someone logs on the website they get redirected to a "No results found" page and in the URL there is a permalink that it does exist! And it does show up results when I am logged in as an administrator.

[Log in page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q7XJ.png) 
[After logging in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry6NT.png)

I have tried everything, updates, deactivating plugins, cache etc etc.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I also asked the hosting company, they said everything is good on their side.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the "My Account" page from `/my-account/` to `/my-profile/`. This should be the page that contains WooCommerce's shortcode for user profile page.

Either switch it back, or just visit Settings -> Permalinks and re-save the settings in order to resolve permalinks/redirect errors.

Also, in your main menu there is a link for your user to go to "My Profile" that links to `/my-account`. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: I did this a couple of times, tried with putting the shortcode to another page, that is why my profile exists. Re-saved the permalinks, yet nothing happened.